# Design consideration to have User Exit in a software product

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, aspectj

We develop product and these products have business logic implemented as EJB. Idea is to provide a User Exit (an extension point which user can override the default behavior). It should be a common problem in product development, but I don't see any design pattern or abstraction mechanism to support override of business logic written in Java.

User exit can either be a overridden Bean class or a groovy script. Are there any design patterns or design considerations to develop products in which EJB's can be overridden using some Java class or a script?

Can anything be done using AspectJ to dynamically decide whether the default implementation should be used or a method in user specific implementation (overridden user exit code) should be used?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to override your EJB functionality?

Comment: It need not be a user, it can be a configuration team or client services team. Not just EJB, it can be any class. EJB override is one of them.

Comment: That generally sound like a bad idea. Wouldn't some event hooks be able to provide the functionality you require? If you want you can allow configuration of some bean overriding if you use DI/IOC...

Comment: First, I don't mean the whole product can be overridden. Let me give you an example, cost of shipping a product from one place to another can be calculated differently by different company. This logic can be overridden and I hope its a valid scenario.

Earlier we used Spring and EJB 2.1, we are now planning for EJB 3. Am worried whether using both Spring and EJB 3 will be a overkill.

Comment: In that case you can use strategy to implement the logic. And then do the wiring with spring or something. Provide a way to customize the configuration files and you should be ok.

Comment: Are you aware of any concrete samples for doing so using EJB 3, JPA, Spring 3? Also are there any design pattern around?

Comment: What is your goal: is it providing an option for user to override the default behavior, if that is so why doesn't the normal method override serve your need ? You need to blend your understanding of a pattern, better understand your current problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspect Oriented Programming is the way to go. AOP using Spring 3 or Plain AspectJ enables user to override the existing feature.

Refer AspectJ in Action book for more information.

Hope it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you comments I'd recommend Strategy pattern to implement the pluggable logic algorithms.

Then use an IOC container like Spring to wire the classes in place.

Allow a user/client to override this configuration if necessary with their own. So anyone interested can simply implement you interface and override the configs so the application will use that data.

EJB itself now has dependency injection so you may want to look into that as well. You may not need spring to wire your app at all if those provisions are sufficient. Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with them to know if custom configs are possible.